# hyperlink in datagrid not getting disabled in firefox

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have added a hypelink column in datagrid.
In  Rowdatabound event ,based on some condition want to make the hyperlink enable or disable.

This works fine in IE.

But in firefox The hyperlink shows disabled but when i click on it a blank popup gets opened.

Please suggest.

Comment: how do you disabling hyperlink? please provide some code

Comment: Hyperlink hlnk = (Hyperlink)grdCoDEList.Rows[i].FindControl("hlnkstatus");
Hlnk.enabled=false;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add attribute for your hyperlink

```
 href="javascript:void(0)"

 Hlnk.Attributes.Add("href","javascript:void(0)");
```